# Setting the value of a text field dependent on the value of another field

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uitextfield

I have two `UITextField`s. The first text field is called `personBMI` and expresses a number. The second is `gaugeWeight`. I want my `gaugeWeight` field to express a word based upon whether the `personBMI` `UITextField` is less than a value, in between two values (e.g., 20-24), or greater than a value.

I know this `if`/`then` statement is supposed to be expressed as part of my `IBAction`. How would I code for my `gaugeWeight` field to express a word defining the result of the `personBMI` field, based upon it being less than, between, or greater than a value?

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this would be a start...

```
CGFloat bmi = [self.personBMI intValue];
NSString *classification = @"Unclassified";

if (bmi <= 16.0f) {
    classification = @"Severely underweight";
} else if (bmi <= 18.5f) {
    classification = @"Underweight";
} // the rest

self.gaugeWeight.text = classification;
```

Comment: My IBAction is as follows:-(IBAction)calculate:(id)sender {
    float floatPersonBMI=[personWeight.text floatValue]*703/ ([personHeight.text floatValue] *[personHeight.text floatValue]);
    NSString *stringPersonBMI=[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%f",floatPersonBMI];
    personBMI.text=stringPersonBMI;.....so I want to make an "if,then" based upon that IBAction to return text in another UITextField similar to as you mentioned above with "severely underweight" and "underweight"

Answer (score 0):

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()<UITextFieldDelegate>
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *personBMI;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *gaugeWeight;
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.personBMI.delegate = self;
    [self.personBMI addTarget:self action:@selector(textFieldDidChange) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(void)textfieldDIdChange{
    if ([self.personBMI.text floatValue]< 20 && [self.personBMI.text floatValue] > 24) {
        self.gaugeWeight.text = @"Put some text here";
    }
}

@end
```

Hope this helps.